# Creating HazelCast cluster running on multiple docker containers

Tags: docker, hazelcast

Does anyone know what configuartion needs to be done in Hazelcast.xml if we want to form Hazelcast cluster between its instances running on multiple docker containers. Should we provide 127.0.0.1 as address of member or the address should be that of docker host? Also does local.localAddress property needs to point to docker host address?

Edit :

We did some changes by setting the public ip and is able to form cluster but with the limitation that while defining port mapping in docker run command port of host should be same as port of container if we set different port of host and map it to hazelcast port like 8047:5071 it doesn't work it has to be 5701:5701, any idea why such a behaviour

Comment: Which environment do you want to deploy to? Any kind of service discovery (zookeper, eureka, kubernetes, ...) available?

Comment: There is no service discovery its just two different machines in same subnet running docker containers having hazelcast instances

Comment: @PunitGoel if your docker containers are in different machines, how you form a cluster? (by multicast or specifying ip address of machines in hazelcast.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the `public-address`property in hazelcast config as the ip of the host machine . This will allow the nodes to join the cluster.

```
 <network>
    <public-address>host-machine-ip</public-address>
</network>
```

Comment: We are setting the public ip and is able to form cluster but with the limitation that while defining port mapping in docker run command port of host should be same as port of container if we set different port of host and map it to hazelcast port like 8047:5071 it doesn't work it has to be 5701:5701, any idea why such a behaviour

Comment: By default , hazelcast will try to join using 5071 port . but when you map the host port as 8047 , it cant find that . What you can do is provide the mapped port as a member in the next node . like `<member>memberIp:8047</member>`